# CSS selector that is based on an occurence of character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have several rows with these IDs:

```
<tr id='0'></tr>
<tr id='0-0'></tr>
<tr id='0-0-0'></tr>
<tr id='0-1'></tr>
```

Now, given that I only know the first character, is it possible to return the rows with 1 dash only? I mean 0-0, 0-1, but not the 0-0-0. I know that there's a css selector that query element with ID that starts with (below) but it returns the elements that I don't want to. I wonder if there's an easy way to query it?

```
jQuery('[id^="0-"]')
```

Thanks

Comment: not in pure CSS (no single char wildcard), gather as few as you can, then use JS to filter the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tr').each(function() {
    str = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
    if (str.length == 2) {
      alert($(this).attr('id'));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id='0'></tr>
  <tr id='0-0'></tr>
  <tr id='0-0-0'></tr>
  <tr id='0-1'></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you could eliminate a lot of them by using CSS attrib selectors to avoid looping ALL the rows... `id[*='-']`